# blender 2.8: why do I need to scale 10x on STL export?

Tags: export, scale

I am developing a 3d model for a 3D print:

[image: 3d model]

The unit system is metric, and the length is set to millimeters. In order to get the size right, I need to do the STL export scale of 10x:

[image: STL Export]

which shows a "correct" model during Prusa slicing:

[image: Prusa Slicer]

Why do I need to do 10x STL Export scaling?

I also applied the scale transformation:

[image: applied scale tranformation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you apply the scale transformation after adjusting the scale ?

ctrl+ A --> Apply scale

then try it

Comment: Hi @manjula, thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion without too much success. Any other ideas?